# Querying data and returning an ordered array by a column value

Tags: mysql, sorting

I understand how to return a single value based on organizing column values in ascending order like so:

```
SELECT username FROM accounts ORDER BY highscore DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I'm wondering if there is a way (i'm sure there is ) to return those values in an ordered array, from the table that isn't organized based off of the `highscore` value.

To clarify: I would like the returned array of rows to be ordered in ascending order based off of integer values in a column called `highscore`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps just remove the `LIMIT 1` and change `DESC` to `ASC`?

`SELECT username FROM accounts ORDER BY highschore ASC;`

Comment: By Original query, you mean the query in my question? Also I would like the returned array to be sorted by integer values in the `highscore` column in ascending order.

Comment: Updated my post above.

Comment: And that would return the whole array, not jus the top value?

Comment: It will return a table (result set) of 1 column and as many rows as there are records in that table. The top value was only being returned because of the `LIMIT 1`.